# Self hosted dropbox

Tags: windows, file-sharing

Does anyone know of a file sharing/syncing software that works like dropbox but is self hosted? It could be centralized with a live server that controls everything or decentralized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some similar freeware/Open Source projects:

- http://sparkleshare.org/
- http://owncloud.org/
- http://ifolder.com/ifolder

And probably more.

Answer (score 10):

I used [`Unison`](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) for years before I caved and went with Dropbox (it's the addiction to mobile devices that finally forced me off).

It's free, it syncs to your servers, it runs on any platforms, it has a ton of customization options. You can configure it to have a central server ("star-architecture") or just use it peer-to-peer.

- Unlike Dropbox: it actually does handle merge, which makes it great for programming or anything else that is text-based. Git/Mercurial could do that, but...
- Unlike full-blown source control, it doesn't force you to check anything in, or think about all the other complexity of a revision control. Rsync does that, but...
- Unlike `rsync` and friends, it understands moves/renames/deletes - so you're never trying to figure out which direction to sync in.

Give it a try!

Comment: Although you answered the question, I am uncomfortable with the implication that a simple sync tool can be a replacement for source control.  Versioning, Diffs, Branching and Merging of Branches all come to mind.

Comment: @Joshua: Yikes, I'm uncomfortable with that implication, too! Never suggested sync is a replacement for SCM. Rather: that if you're so frustrated with sync that you're bringing in the big guns of source control, there are alternative solutions. I'd never use Unison or Dropbox for SCM, of course.

Comment: It looks like Union is no longer under development

Answer (score 0):

Some find hosting subversion locally a good solution (and making it available on the net via ssl vpn like OpenVPN)